# Segmentation fault bug while trying to run Rails with Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie to RoR. Just trying some hands-on.

I’ve done the following things:

Installed Ruby 2.0.0-p481 (x64) (set env paths)

Installed DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx

Installed MySQL Server 5.6.19 (set env paths)

gem install mysql2 --no-rdoc --no-ri -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include"' (Success)

Then I created a test.rb file with the following code just to test mysql

```
require 'mysql2'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(host: 'localhost', username: 'root', password: '')

sql = 'select NOW() as timestamp'

result = client.query(sql)

result.each do |row|
  puts row['timestamp']
end
```

Then I issued following command:

```
ruby test.rb
```

This is a glimpse of error:

C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.0.0/mysql2-0.3.16/mysql2/mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [x64-mingw32]

After it, there are more than 500+ lines or error. I’m using Windows 8.1(x64).

Someone can say that this question is a duplicate and has been asked several times and I accept it but I found no solution for it anywhere.

Comment: Are you able to connect to mysql from console?

Comment: Yes @YevgeniyAnfilofyev I am able to connect to mysql.

Comment: Any help will be much appreciated.